# How to use floating-point storage for time data type

Tags: postgresql, datetime

At Postgres documentation page [Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), it says:

> For the time types, the allowed range of p is from 0 to 6 when
>   eight-byte integer storage is used, or from 0 to 10 when
>   floating-point storage is used.

I tried to produce SQL statement with `time(p)`, when `p=10`? I always get

> WARNING:  TIME(10) precision reduced to maximum allowed, 6

No matter if I put seconds in float or not. I realize I'm missing something very obvious. Please give an example when p=10.

Comment: Just guessing but 8 bits to a byte so it should be "Int64" or "bigint" in postgres lingo

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand beyond times being represented as 64-bit integers?

Comment: @Blrfl updated question

Comment: Right above that line that you quoted is a complete description of the difference between integer and floating-point time storage, including the situations where one or the other is used. What didn't you understand from that paragraph?

Comment: can you please give an example of sql statement with time(p), when p=10?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the linked page you provide:

> **Note:** When timestamp values are stored as eight-byte integers (currently the default), microsecond precision is available over the full range of values. When timestamp values are stored as double precision floating-point numbers instead **(a deprecated compile-time option)**, the effective limit of **precision might be less than 6**. ...

What this says is that in order for timestamp values to be stored as double precision floating-point (and to allow precision up to 10), you need to compile Postgres yourself with that option.

It also says that the precision is then not exactly 10 but it varies depending on the value and may even be less than 6 for some (very high or very low) values.

Comment: thank you for (a deprecated compile-time option) emphasis - at last I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of PostgreSQL didn't appear to store DOUBLE PRECISION values exactly, which was likely the underlying cause of this issue. I was recently working with a colleague who was using PostgreSQL v10 from four years ago.

We found that stored values of file modification timestamps (presented as a float by the stat library call) were frequently retrieved as a slightly imprecise value, ruining the operation of the software.

I'm happy to say that an upgrade to version 14 (I'm currently using 16) fixed the issue, and floats now appear to be stored at full precision.

Comment: I should perhaps have added these are out-of-the-box installations using the `brew` utility. YMMV.

Comment: Are you saying that later versions of Postgres store DOUBLE PRECISION values exactly?

Comment: Well I'm not sure you can generalise from my limited experience, but I developed with pgsql 16 and never saw a comparison error. The same software run on pgsql 10 gave comparison errors on most values, of the order of 10e-5. I've drawn my own conclusions. YMMV ;-)